# Outlook 2010: show tasks only, not flagged e-mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 (on my To-Do List -- the default view when I click the Tasks button in the left sidebar), I only want to see *tasks*, not flagged e-mails. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a filter. When you select Tasks, and with your To Do List selected, click on View in the ribbon (at the top) and then click on View Settings.

From here, you can filter.

For your need, I think you'll need to use Conditional Formatting where you can unselect read and unread emails.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot and the attention. Unfortunately, I don't have Unread messages in my Conditional Formatting list. I can't seem to add my own screen shot to this comment, but it shows my Conditional formatting list with only 5 itmes, and they all end with the word "tasks" (completed/unread/read, overdue, etc.)

Comment: Conditional formatting isn't going to remove the emails from the To-Do list, it will only alter their appearances.  You will instead wish to use the "Filter..." view setting.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to verify in Outlook 2010, but in Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20754), you can set a Filter in the To-Do list advanced view settings.

To do this, add a new Filter in the Advanced tab for "Message Class" contains "task":

[image]

This will hide all flagged emails from the To-Do list, and only show tasks.